# Is the "one-past-the-end" pointer of a non-array type a valid concept in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

The C++ standard [sec 5.7] says:

> If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past
>   the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.

So, am I correct in assuming that pointers one-past-the-end of other types than arrays are undefined?

For example:

```
int a = 0;
vector<int> v(&a, (&a)+1);
```

The above snippet compiles and works just fine (with g++), but is it valid?

Comment: I would like to comment about whether `pointers one-past-the-end of other types than arrays are undefined?`. **Pointers** are always defined, since they are simply numbers, addresses. The **value** by this pointer is undefined however. You must not dereference these pointers. But `vector` constructor doesn't dereference them, so it's ok.

Comment: True, but the address space is not infinite. So there is a pointer to the very last element in address space. Incrementing that pointer would make no sense.

Comment: Pointers are not simply numbers. The C++ standard makes it very clear that you can't use arbitrary addition and subtraction with pointers. In particular the practice to use a pointer to one before an array to accommodate 1-based algorithms causes undefined behavior. AFAIK there are or used to be computer architectures, where loading a value that does not point to valid memory into a pointer register could cause a trap.

Comment: "Pointers are always defined, since they are simply numbers, addresses." -- Utterly wrong. Ever hear of a segment register?

Comment: Which standard?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit and others, OK, I sincerely admit defeat :) Sorry. It was over-simplified/over-generalized statement. And of course I would not recommend such practice as in snippet above for regular use (especially because since c++11 we can initialize vectors of a few items with initializer lists).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, it is legal. 5.7(4) - one paragraph before your quote - says: "For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to a nonarray object behaves the same as a pointer to the
first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type."

Comment: you mean "valid", not "legal", i presume. otherwise a lot of programmers may have to go to jail.

Comment: Yes. 'legal' = "valid, according to the C++ language specification"

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: unless the nasal demons get them first.

Comment: Just to confirm, this is still the case all the way up to C++17 (which, as it happens, moves the text to a footnote and rewrites it slightly).

Comment: Current wording from [basic.compound/3]

http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3

"...an object of type T that is not an array element is considered to belong to an array with one element of type T."