# C++ inheritance of preincrement operator

Tags: c++

i have the following two classes:

```
     class MyClass
     {
       friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const MyClass& );   
       friend int operator+(const MyClass &, const MyClass &);
       public:
         MyClass(const int );
         MyClass(const int, const int);
         MyClass (const MyClass *,  const MyClass *);
         ~MyClass();
         MyClass& operator++();        
         void printValue();
         void setValue(int);           
         int  getValue() const;
       private:
         int value;     
     };


   class DevClass : public MyClass
   {
     public: 
       DevClass(const int, const char *s); 
       char getId() const;
       void setId(char *s);           

   private:
       char id; 
   };
```

Implementation of operator++ is the following:

```
 MyClass& MyClass::operator++() 
  {
   this->value +=1;
   return *this;
  }
```

Now, if I use the operator with the derived class:

```
 DevClass *dev=new DevClass(10,'c');
 ++dev;
```

"dev" seems to point somewhere else in memory. Why ? Why friend operator are not inherited ? This is a class exercise, so i need to address the problem.
Thank you !.

Comment: `DevClass dev = new DevClass(10, 'c')`: Why are you using `new` here? Why are you using `new` and not assigning the result to a pointer (i.e., `DevClass*`?

Comment: It's a class exercise constraint.

Comment: `DevClass dev=new DevClass(10,'c');` should be a compiler error as you are trying to assign a pointer to a non pointer.

Comment: Copy and paste error, code patched.

Comment: @Pandemia000 As other's have mentioned, since `dev` is a pointer (i.e., `DevClass*`) you need to dereference it to use the increment member function `++(*dev)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the statement `++dev;` you aren't calling `operator++` on the object pointed to by `dev` - you are calling it on `dev` itself, which is a pointer, and by incrementing it you're making it point to something which is probably invalid. To call `operator++` on the `DevClass` instance, you can use:

```
++(*dev);
```

Comment: So, the problem was on several wrong use of the operator *. Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

`dev` is type `DevClass *` which is a pointer and not your class. Did you mean `++(*dev)`?

Answer (score 3):

```
DevClass dev=new DevClass(10,'c');
 ++dev;
```

is not legal code. Your compiler should report that as an error.

If you use:

```
DevClass* dev=new DevClass(10,'c');
 ++dev; // Incrementing the pointer, not the object.
```

it makes sense that `dev` points to a different location, though it is cause for undefined behavior since `dev` points to only one object.

If you use:

```
DevClass dev = DevClass(10,'c');
 ++dev; // Incrementing the object
```

`dev` is the same object before and after the call to `operator++()`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505851/is-the-one-past-the-end-pointer-of-a-non-array-type-a-valid-concept-in-c