# When comparing two addresses, why is that an address is no less than and no more than another address, but they're not equal?

Tags: c++, pointers

I write a code *(in my Windows 11, with Embarcadero C++ and using GNU G++17)* as follows:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a,b;
    cout<<&a+1<<endl<<&b<<endl;
    cout<<(&a+1==&b)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I suppose that, if `&a+1` and `&b` gives the same address value, the statement `&a+1==&b` will returns `1`. However, it returns a `0`.

```
0x78fe1c
0x78fe1c
0
```

---

To clarify this issue, I added some lines of code.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a,b;
    cout<<&a+1<<endl<<&b<<endl;
    cout<<(&a+1<=&b)<<endl;
    cout<<(&a+1>=&b)<<endl;
    cout<<(&a+1==&b)<<endl;
    cout<<(&a+1!=&b)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But the result becomes more confusing:

```
0x78fe1c
0x78fe1c
1
1
0
1
```

It means that, `&a+1` is no more than `&b` and no less than it. In the meantime they are not equal. But why?

Comment: Can't replicate, `fatal error: 'bits/stdc++.h' file not found`.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Comparing two pointers for anything except equality and inequality (`==` or `!=`) gives undefined behaviour unless those pointers both point to something in the same aggregate (or object).   For example, if `a` and `b` are both (references to) elements of the same array, or both are members of the same structure.   For `int a, b;`, `a` and `b` are not in the same aggregate.

Comment: It looks like the pointer is within a 24 bit address space - am I missing something here?  And why would you expect two memory addresses to be consecutive?  Besides, even if they were consecutive you wouldn't be able to compare by adding one - you'd need to add the length of the first to get to the second.

Comment: @headbanger, pointer arithmetic works _if_ they are stored consecutively.

Comment: In addition to the UB issue for pointer comparison, there is no guarantee that `a` and `b` are even located exactly one after the other in  memory. Just as an example when I tried it in MSVC, in Debug build there was quite a large gap between them.

Comment: This is a case where your mental model of how C++ should work is different from how it actually works. The code `&a+1` is not legal, and comparisons between pointers are not legal unless the pointers are both pointing to some part of the same larger object. The results of writing such code are unpredictable (as you have found), the technical term for this is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: @john The code `&a+1` is perfectly legal.

Comment: @headbanger "you'd need to add the length of the first" No, that's not how pointer arithmetic works.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit OK, is that a change then? There was a time when the one past the end rule only applied to arrays

Comment: @john no, for purposes of pointer arithmetic a non-array object is considered to belong to a one-element array https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#compound-3.4 AFAICT this rule was there from day one.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit The [draft standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4) seems confused on this point. The body of the section supports what I was saying, but the note implies that what you are saying is correct.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit OK, I can see now that you are correct. Not sure if there has been a change or if I was always unaware of that part of the standard.

Comment: @john  `&a + 1` is valid in standard C++ (all C++ standards) but not in standard C.    Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505851/is-the-one-past-the-end-pointer-of-a-non-array-type-a-valid-concept-in-c

Comment: @Peter Also C https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p7

Comment: @Peter Thanks, I was a C programmer before becoming a C++ one, so that's probably where I picked that up.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit   I don't see how that para is relevant.   It just says that a pointer to a single object acts like it is a pointer to the first element of an array with one element.   That has no bearing on whether it is valid to add one to such a pointer.

Comment: @Peter Since it is valid to add one to a pointer to an array element, it is also valid to add one to a pointer to a non-array-element, because it acts as a pointer to an element of an array of size one for the purpose of pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @Peter Thanks a lot! I will explore the concepts of undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Peter `<` for pointers is unspecified not undefined behavior.

Comment: @Peter https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.compound#expr.rel-4