# Check if a `std::string` uses small string optimization (SSO)

Tags: c++, string, undefined-behavior

I want to check if a `std::string` value is using the small string optimization (SSO).

I am wondering if this is defined behavior:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>

auto is_sso(const std::string &s) -> bool {
    const auto data = std::data(s);
    const auto ptr_0 = std::addressof(s);
    const auto ptr_1 = std::next(ptr_0);

    const auto data_addr = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(data);
    const auto ptr_0_addr = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(ptr_0);
    const auto ptr_1_addr = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(ptr_1);

    return ptr_0_addr <= data_addr && data_addr < ptr_1_addr;
}
```

- `std::next` should be allowed, as its one past the end, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14505930/476266)
- `reinterpret_cast` to `std::uintptr_t` is explictely allowed, [case 2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast).
- comparing `std::uintptr_t` should be allowed, as they are integer types.

I guess the semantics is implementation defined, as we rely on the behavior of the reinterpret_cast. I am not sure if there is an implementation defined way to detect SSO.

Comment: Short string optimization is not standard, it's implementation details and can't be checked correctly.

Comment: `string s; cout << s.capacity() << "\n";` I'd expect capacity to be **0** without SSO, and **>0** with SSO. Still, it's an implementation detail.

Comment: `std::string{}.capacity()`. https://godbolt.org/z/Kcj81bz96 https://godbolt.org/z/Ehc76Yj3h

Comment: I've seen overriding operator new to have a print statement side affect to find the limit. It's only an effective measure for that specific compiler + version + standard library, though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37118638/1387438

Comment: Yeah, `s.size() <= std::string{}.capacity()` would do the same and is much simpler. Although this one makes different assumptions about the implementation.

Comment: Your approach seems good enough as a proxy measurement. You're not going to use this in production code. Probably you'd use this when profiling or testing implementations, right? It will work 99% of the time... and when it doesn't, you'll be able to figure it out.

Comment: @Chris This won't work in all cases: https://godbolt.org/z/xaGj5oGPj.